# SpringBoot reactive MQTT subscriber blocks on I/O operations

Tags: spring, mqtt, reactive

I need to implement a server that subscribes to an MQTT topic, normalizes and saves data in a reactive way, without blocking the thread during I/O operations. I thought about using Java SpringBoot reactive. I managed to have the following code up and running:

```
package com.reactive.demo;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageProducer;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.MqttPahoClientFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.support.DefaultPahoMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.*;

@Configuration
public class MqttConfig {



    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttPahoClientFactory(@Value ("${broker.uri}") String host){
        var factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        var options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[]{});
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound(@Value ("${broker.uri}") String host, @Value ("${broker.clientId}") String clientID, @Value ("${broker.topics}") String[] topics) {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(host, clientID, topics);
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                //Perform normalization and save into database
            }
        };
    }



}
```

The problem with this code is that `MessageHandler handler()` does not allow me to insert the payload in the database without blocking the thread.

Comment: Blocking *which* thread?

Comment: The thread handling the message. I want to avoid having it to wait for the db insert to end.

Comment: Ok, are you hoping to be able to handle another message in the meantime? In such case, you might want to simply switch to another channel implementation, like `ExecutorChannel`. `DirectChannel` message handler invocation always happens within the sender's thread, which makes it unsuitable for your scenario. No need to juggle threads within the message handler itself.

Comment: The server receives a huge amount of data in a little time, so having each thread waiting on the db insert could saturate Netty's threads. Is like I need handleMessage() to return a Mono<Void> instead.

Comment: Ok, let's take a step back. The DB insert has to happen on *some* thread. It's not like if you fire-and-forget the DB operation, your app will suddenly use fewer threads.  The DB has a connection pool of certain size `n`, meaning at most `n` threads can insert data concurrently at a given moment. The crucial question is: do you want to be able to handle `n` messages simultaneously, or more? If the answer is `n`, then I stand by my previous comment, and you likely want the `ExecutorChannel`'s thread pool to be of size `n`. If the answer is 'more', then you might want to check out `QueueChannel`

Comment: Thank you for your patience. However I mean that whenever a new message comes, there is a certain thread handling that message. It performs some processing on the data and then makes a call to a database to insert the data. This call is blocking, right? I want this thread to return to the thread pool so that it can be useful for other requests CPU operations. Whenever the insert has been done, some thread can retake control, and return nothing, in my case. I just wish to keep threads as less idle as possible.

Comment: What you have is an XY problem. You want to free the thread that is handling the message from the queue as soon as possible. You *think* the solution to that problem is to offload some part of processing to some sort of background mechanism, within the handler itself. I'm trying to explain to you that you don't need to do that at all.

Comment: Spring Integration is designed to provide useful abstractions that you can declaratively use to guide the execution semantics. I feel that this level of abstraction is, well, too abstract to illustrate my point, so let's strip one abstraction away: if you use `ExecutorChannel`, the message handling thread will submit a task to an executor. After which it is *free to do other tasks* because *no other processing happens at this time*, that's precisely the point. It returns to the pool almost immediately